# Get links to all files inside a folder in Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to get direct links (without the Dropbox header) to all files inside a Dropbox folder via their API?

Answer (score -2):

Yes. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media.

(Adding more text to satisfy minimum character constraint.)

Comment: The link is broken now. That is why SO guidelines suggest outlining the main part of the answer here also, apart from adding the link. I guess that is why there is minimum character constraint.